# Scrolling "too long" command doesn't work properly

Tags: fish

Assume I want to invoke a tool with a lot of options, like:

```
$ somescript --option1 --option2 --option3 --option4 --option5 whatever even more stuff
```

But the width of the terminal doesn't allow to have that thing on a "single line".

That alone isn't a problem, but with fish, there is a problem with scrolling.

When I enter that extra-wide command, at some point, there will be a line break:

> $ somescript --option1 --option2 --option3 --option4 --option5
>
> whatever even more stuff

All fine so far. While typing such a lengthy command, I can scroll forth and back at any point. Works as expected. So, assume I entered the command, made a mistake, and now want to remove --option4.

The normal thing: use "arrow up" to get to that command in the history, to then use "arrow left" to scroll within the command. And now something weird happens.

Everything is fine while the cursor is within the second line. But when the cursor moves to the first line ... after 3 to 5 more "arrow left" strokes, the cursor moves UP another line. Then it sits **above** the first line of the command. There is also a *vertical* jump of a few characters.

In other words: as soon as a command is longer than the width of the terminal, I am unable to scroll into the first line reliably. The cursor shows up somewhere, and it is really hard to guess where it *really* sits at any moment. Which makes it almost impossible to edit anything in that first line.

This is on MacOs, using iterm 3.2.9 and fish version 3.0.2 installed via brew.

Comment: This type of behavior usually means that fish and your terminal have different ideas about the width of some characters. If you command consists solely of ASCII chars then that isn't the issue but if you have any non-ASCII chars (e.g., emoji) then that is the first thing to investigate. Also, for complex editing you can also tell fish to drop you into a real editor via [meta-e] or [meta-v] or whatever keys you have bound the `edit_command_buffer` function to.

Comment: You should open a bug report at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new

Comment: @KurtisRader I finally wrote up a defect, and the outcome is rather frustrating (see my self answer). It is not a fish bug, but a general MacOs unicode/terminal thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote up defect [6014](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/6014) on github. Outcome is rather frustrating.

The problem is: the Mac terminal(s) all handle certain unicode characters the wrong way. "Normally" that isn't a problem, but when you use one of those fish prompts that give you the git status (like `AcidHub` which is my favorite) ... fish can't compute/determine the exact line width, and there you go.

So, basically, when using fish on MacOs, option space is limited to:

- use the defaults, which (when using special prompts, like `AcidHub` will lead to scrolling issues)
- adapt the fish prompt accordingly (in my case, I replaced all special unicode chars with something simpler). It doesn't look that great, but scrolling simply works again.

And a completely different and unexpected solution to the problem: I am using iterm2 on my Mac, and iterm2 just added a "status bar" section. That can be easily configured, and of course, it already has a status bar component that tells you about git status.

Thus my solution: I changed the fish prompt to just give the PWD, and all the other things that the AcidHub prompt has to offer, are now "iterm2 status bar" components!

Comment: The prompt can display git status, it just can't do it using those characters. Many of fish's sample prompts display the git status using other characters.

Comment: They're in tools/web_config/sample_prompts, which you've also got on your system, most likely under /usr/local/share/fish (or share/ in the fish repo). A simple search shows acidhub, classic_vcs, informative_vcs, lonetwin, nim, robbyrussell, sorin, terlar all have some form of vcs support.

Comment: Or write your own - fish ships the `fish_vcs_prompt` helper function, which calls `__fish_git_prompt`, `__fish_hg_prompt` and `__fish_svn_prompt` as necessary, all of which feature a variety of knobs to twist.

Comment: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/tree/master/share/tools/web_config/sample_prompts

Comment: @faho Interestingly enough, I found a very different, yet convenient solution for me ... see my updates ;-)